# Reduce the number of functions with lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

The number of indexes in the object `buffer[[1:11]]` and `year[[1:11]]` correspond to the years from `1:11`. I classify them by wave and then I store the lits into a single object. Is there a way in which I can avoid to repeat 11 times and I can use a single function?
Thanks in advance

```r
year_1 <- lapply(seq(length(buffer[[1]])), function(x) year[[1]][which(!is.na(over(SpatialPoints(data.frame(year[[1]]$X_proj,year[[1]]$Y_proj)), buffer[[1]][[x]]))), ])
year_2 <- lapply(seq(length(buffer[[2]])), function(x) year[[2]][which(!is.na(over(SpatialPoints(data.frame(year[[2]]$X_proj,year[[2]]$Y_proj)), buffer[[2]][[x]]))), ])
...
year_11 <- lapply(seq(length(buffer[[11]])), function(x) year[[11]][which(!is.na(over(SpatialPoints(data.frame(year[[11]]$X_proj,year[[11]]$Y_proj)), buffer[[11]][[x]]))), ])
```

```
buffers_years <- list(year_1, year_2, ..., year_11)
```

Comment: This looks like a job for `Map`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: How does deleting work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested `lapply()`:

```r
analysis_buf <- lapply(1:11, \(i) {
  lapply(seq(length(buffer[[i]])), \(x) {
    year[[i]][which(!is.na(over(SpatialPoints(data.frame(year[[i]]$X_proj, year[[i]]$Y_proj)), buffer[[i]][[x]]))), ])
  }
})
```

Also as @Roland's comment, this might be a `Map` case:

```r
analysis_buf <- Map(\(lst1, lst2) {
  lapply(seq(length(lst1)), \(x) lst2[which(!is.na(over(SpatialPoints(data.frame(lst2$X_proj, lst2$Y_proj)), lst1[[x]]))), ])
}, buffer, year)
```